# WH-movement with complex sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm editing a biography in which the author, who isn't a native English speaker, stated the following:

> I started a business at the age of 21 and had no idea **what were** the
>   most important skills I should work on.

This naturally didn't sound correct and my kneejerk reaction was WH-movement:

> I started a business at the age of 21 and had no idea **what** the most
>   important skills I should work on **were**.

Not the most elegant sentence, but barring adding extra words or removing existing words, isn't this grammatically sound? Maybe I've read it so many times that I've lost objectivity.

Comment: It's a *free relative*, and both your examples sound okay to me.

Comment: _…what the most important skills were_. Not even German word order would stick the verb after a second relative clause.

Comment: I prefer the edited version, though if you are allowed to be creative I'd change slightly: I started a business at the age of 21 and had no idea what skills I should focus on developing.

Comment: @KarlG: So you're proposing ...what the most important skills were I should work on? Sorry, that sounds horrible.

Comment: @SConroy: Funny enough, that's exactly what I ended up with))) But this is for the sake of argument. I insisted that the edited version IS grammatically correct and syntactically acceptable and ran into some naysayers. Thank you!

Comment: Well, suit yourself. You're not exactly starting out with a well-constructed sentence. Your second sentence sounds like someone vaguely remembering to keep the subject before the verb in an indirect question and then went overboard.

Comment: The first one sounds better to me ...

Comment: @PhilSweet: There are a million ways to make it sound better, but the idea is not to add or remove any words and end up with something that's grammatically sound.

Comment: @PhilSweet: you don't need to repeat _skills_ and you've transformed a sentence with one indirect question into one with two.

Comment: I'm really surprised to see that some of you actually find the original sentence grammatical.

Comment: *What was the problem?* *What were the skills?* *What were the most important skills?* The first sentence is grammatical although awkward. How to make it sound better is a different question—and one that's mostly subjective.

Comment: I agree that the original is better; it looks clumsy to have 'were' stuck at the end of the sentence like that.